# Optemizing basic auth: Save user authentification for follow up requests

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using the [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) tutorial to secure my Web-API calls with basic auth. Basically it checks if there is a auth header on the request and then proves this header against a database:

```
public static bool CheckPassword(string user, string password)
{
    //Do a Database checkup
    if(CheckDB(user,password)) { 
        //if true, set the principal
        var identity = new GenericIdentity(user);
        SetPrincipal(new GenericPrincipal(identity,null));
    }
    else {
        //return 401...
    }
}
private static void SetPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
{
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
}
```

This is working fine. But it queries the database for every request I do. Even when I just request a JavaScript file.

I like to optimize this process and just call `CheckDB()` on the first request. All following request should not need another database request. Is it possible to save the Principal? I tried to check `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` but it seams to reinitialize on every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. If you have a simple topology with only a single machine handling requests for a relatively small number of users you could implement an in memory cache of usernames and passwords that you can use to efficiently validate subsequent calls. You could implement this using something like ConcurrentDictionary that keys off the username and gives the password, although there are security considerations to such an approach (do you really want passwords to be in memory all the time?).
2. Set a cookie after a username/password pair has been validated. The cookie could contain something like the timestamp after which the username/password should be revalidated, along with some kind of hash that's generated by a means that only the server knows (and that it can use to validate that it set the timestamp).

With either of these approaches the "CheckPassword" method would either compare the password with the one from the cache, or checking the cookie, and if the result is satisfactory directly create a new principal without calling the database.